# Get the line of last occurrence of a particular string in a text file in java

Tags: java

I want the line of last occurrence  of a particular string in a text file

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\prudra\\Desktop\\Axalta\\20180406114505\\activemq.log_app1"));
int i = 0;
String str = file.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter search ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the environment you want to execute the script (Dev/QA/Prod)");
String name = sc.nextLine();
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
 final String lineFromFile = file.nextLine();
 i++;
 if (lineFromFile.contains(name)) {
  //System.out.println("file.txt");
 }
}
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you wanted something like this?

```
int lastIndex= 0;
//start of loop
if (lineFromFile.contains(name)) {
  lastIndex = i;
}

//end of loop

if (lastIndex != 0) {
    System.out.println(lastIndex);
} else {
    System.out.println("Line not found");
}
```

Or maybe only increment the i in condition

```
int i = 0;
//start of loop
if (lineFromFile.contains(name)) {
  i++;
}

//end of loop

if (i != 0) {
    System.out.println(i + 1); //because you start i from 0
} else {
    System.out.println("Line not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\prudra\\Desktop\\Axalta\\20180406114505\\activemq.log_app1"));
int i = 0;
int index = 0;
String str = file.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter search ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the environment you want to execute the script (Dev/QA/Prod)");
String name = sc.nextLine();
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
 final String lineFromFile = file.nextLine();
 i++;
 if (lineFromFile.contains(name)) {
  //saves index of occurance
  index = i;
 }
}
System.out.println(index);
}
```

I guess this is what you're looking for. Just need a variable to hold the line of the last occurrence found. Since you just want the last, after reading all lines `index` will hold the last one. In case you want the first you can return `i` after finding the first one. If you need x occurrence you would need to keep a count in another variable.

EDIT: Not sure if by line you mean line number of line text, if it's the text, instead of using a index to hold the line number, you can use a string to hold the line text like `lineText = lineFromFile;`

Answer (score 0):

Store the last line in a local variable and access it out-of the loop.

Example:

```
 Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\prudra\\Desktop\\Axalta\\20180406114505\\activemq.log_app1"));
int i = 0;
String str = file.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter search ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the environment you want to execute the script (Dev/QA/Prod)");
String name = sc.nextLine();
String lastLine="";
int lastLineNumber=-1;
while (file.hasNextLine()) {
 final String lineFromFile = file.nextLine();
 i++;
 if (lineFromFile.contains(name)) {
   lastLine=lineFromFile;
   lastLineNumber=i;
  //System.out.println("file.txt");
 }
}
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println("Last Line: "+lastLine);
System.out.println("Last Line Number: "+lastLineNumber);
}
```

This actually works as long as the file pointer starts reading from the first-line through the last-line of the file. Since at the end of the loop you are storing the last occurrence of the line of text you want, then you can access it later.